# How to integrate the java code written on local machine to Serde for hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, ebcdic, hive-serde

I have written code (java)  for the conversion of EBCDIC to ASCII on the local machine. 
And we are writing a serde for hive query which would provide the ability for Hive to read the EBCDIC file and convert it into ASCII file at run time. 
So that's why we are writing a SerDe. 
So how to integrate this code on. Local machine to SerDe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to integrate this code on. Local machine to SerDe ?

Your class must implement `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDe` then you need to build the jar and move it cluster

- Now include the JAR in `ADD JAR <jar/location/in/cluster>`
- Use class SerDe class in **TABLE CREATION** or **ALTERING** like below

  `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'classpath.of.implemented.SerDe.in.jar'`

[how-to-use-a-serde-in-apache-hive](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-a-serde-in-apache-hive/)

Comment: thank you .could you please elaborate on how to implement org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDe

Comment: [Above added link](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-a-serde-in-apache-hive/) have an example in it with a heading **Developing a SerDe**